# android - unable to parse apparent integers as integers

Tags: android, sqlite

For an app I am developing for a client, I have a large SQLite database of golf courses that is repopulated with new data as part of versioned updates, namely, new data is added onto the existing records already in the database.

A portion of these updates are a mixture of numeric and text data that are automatically exported as a .txt file with comma delimiters ( but can also be exported as a .rtf, though I would think that .txt would be much easier to work with). An example of such an output .txt file is given [at this Pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/CahfrgVk).

The code that handles reading the .txt file in and grabbing each value from each line is

```
// Insert records from csv file into database
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in_s));
        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] RowData = line.split(", ");
                int numEntries = RowData.length;
                if(numEntries == 5) {
                    // Course Insertion Row
                    //                      "Scenic Hills CC - WHITE", 70.0, 124, "Pensacola", "FL"
                    courseHelper.createCourse(RowData[0], Double.valueOf(RowData[1]), Integer.parseInt(RowData[2]), RowData[3], RowData[4]);
                    mCurrentLine++;
                }
                else {
                    // Hole Insertion Row
                    //                      1, 1, 4, 416
                    holeHelper.createHole(Integer.parseInt(RowData[0]), Integer.parseInt(RowData[1]), Integer.parseInt(RowData[2]), Integer.parseInt(RowData[3]));
                    mCurrentLine++;

                }                   
            }
        }
```

The client, who wishes to attempt to handle the updating of the course database himself, is not terribly tech-savvy, and is rather insistent that the method of him sending me the new .txt file for each update be used.

However, as some of the .txt files I have been receiving have been growing larger, I have started to get "java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '6' as integer"-type errors on about 2 lines for every 100 lines the file is in length, with different numbers other than 6, based on which line of the .txt file causes the exception.

Opening the .txt file in Bless Hex Editor, I have noticed that at the start of every line that causes a NumberFormatException, that the non-ascii character (in hex, EF BB) is right before the leading integer. Obviously, this non-ascii character is crashing the `parseInt()` method.

After that long explanation, I have 2 main questions:

1. What would be the best way to fix the root issue, even though the placement of these non-ascii characters appear to be pseudo-random throughout the file?
2. If a good fix for #1 is not possible, what would be a good way of "sanitizing" the .txt file before it is read in in the relevant activity?

Any help provided would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a byte order mark (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). EF BB looks like a piece of the BOM that identifies a UTF-8 encoding at the beginning of a text stream.

I would ask how the client is producing these files. If whatever process is mashing multiple files together into a larger file, it could be erroneously spitting several BOMs into the final stream.

If you can't fix the process that produces these files, you could code around it. Try catching the number format exception, rewind the stream (if possible/necessary) and test to see if those same two bytes caused it. If so, discard those two bytes and parse the next integer.

Comment: Interesting. I will have to ask the client about how they are producing the files. I know that they are not being mashed together, but I can hopefully figure out how they are outputting them.  As for your workaround, could you give an example of rewinding the stream, etc. that you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Write a wrapper function for `parseInt` that detects the BOM (`if (str.startsWith("\uFEFF"))`) and removes it.